# How to determine if the specific time is between given time range in javascript

Tags: javascript, time, date-comparison, datetime-conversion, datetime-comparison

i want to check var check_val   in between two time  var open_time and var close_time

```
var open_time  = "23:30";
var close_time = "06:30";
var check_val  ="02:30";
if(Date.parse ( check_val ) > Date.parse ( open_time ) && Date.parse ( check_val ) < Date.parse ( close_time )){
    var flag=1;
} else { 
    var flag=2
}
```

the result is always else part

Comment: Do you imply "06:30" is the time of the next day of "23:30" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date.parse()` accepts dates in [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14/) or [ISO8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime/) formats.

In your case, it always returns `NaN`.

```
Date.parse("23:30"); // NaN
```

Using the appropriate Date format works as expected:

```
var open_time = Date.parse("2011-10-09T23:30");
var close_time = Date.parse("2011-10-10T06:30");
var check_val = Date.parse("2011-10-10T02:30");

if( check_val > open_time && check_val < close_time ) {
    var flag=1;
} else { 
    var flag=2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create your own object to hold time and then write a function which uses it:

```
var Time = function(timeString) {
    var t = timeString.split(":");
    this.hour = parseInt(t[0]);
    this.minutes = parseInt(t[1]);
    this.isBiggerThan = function(other) { 
        return (this.hour > other.hour) || (this.hour === other.hour) && (this.minutes > other.minutes);
    };
}

var timeIsBetween = function(start, end, check) {
    return (start.hour <= end.hour) ? check.isBiggerThan(start) && !check.isBiggerThan(end)
    : (check.isBiggerThan(start) && check.isBiggerThan(end)) || (!check.isBiggerThan(start) && !check.isBiggerThan(end));    
}

var openTime = new Time("23:30");
var closeTime = new Time("06:30");
var checkTime = new Time("02:30");

var isBetween  = timeIsBetween(openTime, closeTime, checkTime);
```